# How to avoid content from being appended multiple times

Tags: jquery

On click of the USMarkets text , i am appending some text to the panel , but the issue i am facing is that , the content is being appended multiple times

This is my code

```
$('#usmarket').click(function() {
    var data = tableData();
    $('#usmarket .panel').html(data);
    $('#usmarket .panel').after("<div class='redBox'></div>");
    $(".redBox").empty();
    $(".redBox").html("<p>I am Appended Multiple Times</p>");
});

function tableData() {
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">\
   <tr>\
      <td>3-Nov-2015</td>\
      <td>Gallup US ECI</td>\
      <td>8:30 AM ET</td>\
      <td class="text-center"><i class="indicator_wrap empty "></i></td>\
   </tr>\
   <tr>\
      <td>3-Nov-2015</td>\
      <td>Redbook</td>\
      <td>8:55 AM ET</td>\
      <td class="text-center"><i class="indicator_wrap empty "></i></td>\
   </tr>\
</table>';
    return html;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vztb9sae/5/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: Remove existing elements before adding new. Use `$(".redBox").remove();` Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vztb9sae/10/) _OR_ use `one` to bind click on the element `$('#usmarket').one('click', function()`. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vztb9sae/12/)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the link to work once, use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$('#usmarket').one("click",function() {
  $('#usmarket .panel').html(tableData())
  .after("<div class='redBox'></div>");
  $(".redBox").html("<p>I am Appended Once</p>");
});
```

If you mean appended later, then do not use a class for redBox if you add it more than once, all of them will be added to with $(".redbox").html(...)

Answer (score 0):

there are a bunch of solutions..

one would be to give the table an Id, and check that the id doesn't already exist before adding

```
if($('#yourTable').length === 0)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vztb9sae/6/

another would be to create a local variable

```
var shouldAddTable = true;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vztb9sae/7/

or you could use jquery on() and off()

```
$('#usmarket').on('click', addTable);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vztb9sae/11/

Comment: Actually, not _deprecated_ but preferred methods are [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)